# Slide div in and out of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to airbnb.com's home page and the how it works button.

I've been able to do the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n89z4bz3/

However, I'm unable to achieve the slide effect as well as fixing the visible container to the bottom of the slid in `upper-container`.

My Jquery code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heightVar = 0 - $(window).height();
    $('.upper-container').css('top',heightVar+'px');
    $('.main-container').css('height', $(window).height()+'px');
    $('.click-this').on('click', function(){
        $('.upper-container').css('top', '0');
        $('.main-container').css('margin-top',$('.upper-container').height()+'px');
    });
});
```

My HTML is setup as follows:

```
<div class="upper-container">
    Hidden container
</div>
<div class="main-container">
    Visibile container
    <div class="click-this">
        Click This to Slide Down
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/n89z4bz3/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var heightVar = 0 - $(window).height();
  $('.main-container').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
  $('.click-this').on('click', function() {
    $('.upper-container').animate({
      height: '100px',
      paddingTop: '40px'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.upper-container {
  position: reltive;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: red;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-container {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.click-this {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper-container">
  Hidden container
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  Visibile container
  <div class="click-this">
    Click This to Slide Down
  </div>
</div>
```